# Is there any way to build svg with cross-origin fonts in browser?

Tags: javascript, svg, webfonts

I'm trying to find a way to make a screenshot of DOM-node on client-side. The best option I've come up with is wrapping DOM-node in `<foreignObject>` and placing it to SVG. Then SVG goes to a `canvas` and then it can be converted to all other formats as a `Blob`.

Everything works fine except the fonts. Custom fonts works only in inline SVG, but not in SVG as a separate file. I need to embed them as a Blob.

And here comes a problem: some of these fonts are hosted on Google fonts, so there is no way to get their blobs at runtime because of CORS-restrictions.

I've already tried `html2canvas` library and it is not reliable for my purposes. Same for `dom-to-canvas` and `html-to-canvas`. They don't solve the problem with fonts.

Also I've tried to rasterize all children text-blocks in the DOM-node, but result is far from perfect.

Server-side solution is possible, but I'd like to avoid it.

Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've come up with creating proxy on my server for fetching cors-fonts and css.

I check styles font imported styles and font-face rules and create new ones for svg with embedded fonts and styles.